# Magento 2 - Unset Special Price programmatically

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

I have an import script which imports configs and the variants.

There is set the **special price** if some is set in my import XML document.
If no special price is set, i try to remove the special price. - But it do not
work! - The special price is already set, after save!

```
if ($oProductGroupVariantProductItem->getSpecialpriceBrutto() > 0) {
    $oSimpleProduct->setSpecialPrice($oProductGroupVariantProductItem->getSpecialpriceBrutto());
} else {
    $oSimpleProduct->setSpecialPrice('');
}
```

**what i am doing wrong?**

Thanks
Andre

Comment: try with unset($oProductGroupVariantProductItem->getSpecialpriceBrutto())

Comment: ??? - I want to unset the "$oSimpleProduct" special price value !! Not my Import Data Value Object!

Comment: you can do this in else case of your condition

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Saving the price and forcibly update the product attribute using the resource model worked in my situtation:

```
$product->setSpecialPrice(null);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'special_price');
```

Note: Make sure a $product object has store_id = 0. special_price attribute is global attribute. If store_id won't be 0, this method won't work, then you will try to unset special_price.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to save the product after you updated the attributes.

Try this:

```
$oSimpleProduct->save();
```

Comment: Don't use deprecated `save()`-methods on legacy models. Use the repository instead (see `ProductRepositoryInterface::save()`).